# Unexpected error implementing Tesseract on angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I installed the actual javascript module:

```
npm install tesseract.js --save
```

Also install @types declarations:

```
npm install @types/tesseract.js --save-dev
```

And i import Tesseract in component like :

```
import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js'
```

And my function is :

```js
readOcrByImage(image) {
        Tesseract.detect(image).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        });
    }
```

But when i tried to run my page it will show this following error:
[image]

How can i solve this problem?